# click on li keep open ul with class collapse nav nav-pills nav-stacked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a side bar contain the following code, the problem is when click on li, sub menu disappear but I want to show them when click on one of li and keep open that ul with its li's.

I searched much on internet and saw many examples, at first glance it seems they do not have the problem that I point it out but when I add an address to its href their does not keep open ul too.

```
     <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked text-center" style="padding-    right:2px;" >

             <li>
             <a href="#collapse1" id="btn-1" class="text-center"  data-    toggle="collapse"><span><b>A</b></span>  </a>
                 <ul  class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked text-center collapse " id="collapse1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-1" aria-expanded="false">
                             <li ><a  href="~/A/A-a">A-a</a></li>
                             <li ><a  href="~/A/A-b">A-b</a></li>
                             <li ><a  href="~/A/A-c">A-c</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>               


                   <li>
                         <a href="#collapse2" class="text-center" data-toggle="collapse"><span><b>B</b></span></a>
                         <ul id="collapse2" class="collapse nav nav-pills nav-stacked  text-center collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                             <li ><a  href="~/B/B-a">B-a</a></li>
                             <li ><a  href="~/B/B-b">B-b</a></li>
                          </ul>
                     </li>                                                 
                 </ul>
```

how can I keep open ul with id=collapse1 and collapse2 when click on one on li just when close them that click on their parent li